# Adding records with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database which contains follwoing tables PRODUCTS - PRODUCTHOSTSPOTTEXTS - HOTSPOTTEXTS

PRODUCTHOSTSPOTTEXTS act as a many to many realtionship between the other 2 tables. When I bring that database to VS studio EF model, the many to many reation table is not shown . Instead I have a many to many association between PRODUCTS and HOTSPOTTEXT which is correct.

But when I try to add some records into the HOTSPOTTEXTS table I get an error from EF saying that PRODUCTHOSTSPOTTEXTS is not found

In order to add properly HOTSPOTTEXT to a PRODUCT, I need to add the in HOTSPOTTEXT the Text and ProductID, then in PRODUCTHOSTSPOTTEXTS as a new entry should contains the ProductID and the new HOTSPOTTEXT.ID 
[image: Model]

For adding records I do it as follow

```
PresentationDAL.PresentationEntities ctx = new PresentationEntities();
        var prod = (from p in ctx.Products where p.Id == id select p).FirstOrDefault();

        var hotspot = new HotSpotText();
        hotspot.ProductId = id;
        hotspot.Text = "text 1";
        prod.HotSpotTexts.Add(hotspot);

        hotspot.Text = "text 2";
        prod.HotSpotTexts.Add(hotspot);

        hotspot.Text = "Text 3";
        prod.HotSpotTexts.Add(hotspot);

        ctx.HotSpotTexts.AddObject(hotspot);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks for help
serge

Answer (score 0):

EF will by default expect the name *PRODUCTHOTSPOTTEXTS* for the join table but your table has the name *PRODUCTHO***S***TSPOTTEXTS*.